# How to format a parenthetical citation in a parenthetical phrase?

Tags: parentheses, citation

Specifically, in APA style. I'm talking about this, for example:

> ...where there has been a long history (artefacts have been found (Smith, 2006)) of such matters...

Is it okay to have double closing parentheses like so? What's the proper formatting otherwise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try take a look in this article http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/05/punctuation-junction-parentheses-and-brackets.html

The author suggests use a bracket inside parentheses to create a double enclosure.